# ajax returning true while FALSE

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, function

I am using codeigniter, i have written a function to check if a user password exists which it does. This is my model

1. The model: user

   public function get_some_password($username,$password) {

   ```
       $this->db->where('user_password', $password);
       $this->db->where('user_username',$username);
       $query=$this->db->get('some_users_table');
       if($query->num_rows()==1){
           return true;
       }else{
           return false;
       }
   ```
2. the controller

   public function check_password() {
           $username=$this->uri->segment(3);
           $temp_pass=  $this->input->post('current_password');
           $password=md5($temp_pass);
           $this->user->get_some_password($username,$password);

   ```
   }
   ```

   1. The ajax on the view

   //done on page load

   var success1 = $(".success"); //a div on the view that appears if success
           var error1 = $(".error"); //a div on the view that appears if error
           success1.hide();
           error1.hide();

   ```
       $('#change_password').click(function() {
           var username = $('#username').val();
           dataString2 = $('#changpassword').serialize();
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller_name/check_password/' + username,
               data: dataString2,
               success: function() {
                   $('.success').html('password successfully updated!'),
                           success1.slideDown('slow');

               },
               error: function() {
                   $('.error').html('Wrong current password!'),
                           error1.slideDown('slow');
               }

           });
   ```

The problem: Ajax loads the success div even when the username or password returned is false, where am i missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a correct behavior as jquery error is executed when response code is not 200:

1) You can parse returned value in success method.

e.g.

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data == 'true') {
        // Success
    } else {
        // Error
    }
}
```

2) You can return error code from server 404, 500, 503 ... To trigger execution of error function.

e.g.

```
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
```

note: Header should executed before any output is done.

Try in your controller:

```
public function check_password() {
    $username=$this->uri->segment(3); 
    $temp_pass= $this->input->post('current_password'); 
    $password=md5($temp_pass); 
    if(!$this->user->get_some_password($username,$password)) {
        $this->output->set_status_header('500');
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: and where do i set that header status?

Comment: @Alphy Did not work with codeignater but looks like that can help you http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html. `$this->output->set_status_header()` part

Comment: I have tried your code above and it now just returns false even if true, i have also set the header

Comment: What code did you use? It should be either php fix or javascript fix, not both.

Comment: success: function(data) {
    if (data == 'true') {
        // Success
    } else {
        // Error
    }
}

Comment: I modified mine a small part from success with the above code

Comment: It was just an example double check what is returned as `data` and compare to proper value. Just posted fix for php side that should work. You would need to revert your javascript to original though

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19958/discussion-between-alphy-and-e-p)